# Add arguments to Django signals

Tags: django, arguments, signals

how do I add arguments to Django signals so that the associated receiver can use those arguments? Reading [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/signals/#receiver-functions) I've not been able to figure myself. Thanks

Example:

```
def callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # I want to work with extra here!
    extra = kwargs.get(extra, None)
    if extra:
        # do something with extra
        pass
```

The receiver is connected to the signal this way:

```
pre_save.connect(callback)
```

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#sending-signals

Answer (score 4):

`pre_save` is not a signal that you send, but rather Django emits it by default: changing its arguments is probably very complicated and likely to break things.

On signals you define, you can add all the arguments you want; to see how, look at the docs (kindly linked by @Ignacio).